# Maximum of selected options in multiple select attribute in Magento?

Tags: magento, select, attributes, magento-1.6

I'm making a store of inkcartridges with Magento.

I've made an multiple select attribute with all the printers as an option.
It seems to be not possible to select more than 51 printers, if I do and save the product, there is no error, but if I open the product again. The selected items above the 51 are unselected.

How can I solve this problem?

Please help me, it drives me crazy..

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is, that the backend type of the attribute is set to "varchar" and needs to be "text"

If you look up the db table eav_attribute, and search for your attribute (by attribute_code) you'll notice the backend is set to varchar, change this to "text" and you can then save more than 51 printers.

However, this might clear out all of the currently saved values for that attribute, as it is changing the eav table to _text from _varchar, so do this in a dev environment first.